# "um zu" oder nur "zu"

Tags: conjunction, infinitive

Ich versuche zu verstehen, wann beim Infinitiv mit "zu" das Wort "um" stehen muss / kann / nicht stehen darf. Ich verstehe, was der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/um-zu-zu) dazu sagt, allerdings frage ich mich, ob das alle Fälle behandelt.

1. Ist die attributive Verwendung (*Die Aussicht, in Domburg eine Woche auszuspannen, ist verlockend.*) der einzige Fall, wo kein "um" stehen darf?
2. Gibt es Beispiele, wo das weglassen von "um" zu bevorzugen ist, obwohl beide Möglichkeiten grammatikalisch in Ordnung sind?

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe hierfür jetzt keine Quelle, aber aus meiner Sicht verhält es sich so, dass *um* verwendet wird, wenn eine Begründung, ein Zweck oder ein Ziel für etwas ausgedrückt werden soll:

> Ich bin auf diese Seite gegangen, um eine Antwort zu schreiben

In allen anderen Fällen gibt es aus meiner Sicht für ein *um* keinen Grund. Schon gar nicht kann man sagen, dass bei jedem *zu* auch ein *um* stehen muss. Beispiele dafür:

> Es wird Zeit, den Kuchen zu backen.
>   Hast Du daran gedacht, das Fleisch aufzutauen?

Es kann durch aus Fälle geben, wo man das *um* auch weglassen kann, aber ob es Fälle gibt, wo das sogar die bevorzugte Variante ist, vermag ich nicht zu beurteilen.

Comment: Ein Mensch, der auszog, [um] das Fürchten zu lernen.

Comment: Eher Ziel oder Zweck als Begründung.

Comment: @titus ja, das ist ein Beispiel, wo *um* weggelassen werden kann und das, weil es ein Titel eines Märchens ist, fast ausschließlich so verwendet wird. Dennoch klingt dieser Satz "alt".

Comment: @CarstenS Du hast Recht, ich werde die Antwort anpassen sobald ich was besseres als das Smartphone in die Hände bekomme :-)

Answer (score 0):

Zu = was?

Um zu = warum?

> Ich versuche es Ball spielen zu üben.

Ich versuche es zu üben.  --> Ohne Begründung

> Ich versuche Ball spielen zu üben um Ball spielen zu üben.

Ich versuche es um es zu üben. --> Mit Begründung

---

> Ich drehe mich, um einen besseren Überblick zu bekommen.
>
> ---
>
> Zum Bekommen eines besseren Überblicks drehe ich mich.

(zu und um verkürzt zu zum)