# (Um- Zu) benutzen

Tags: english-to-german

Wann kann man (um zu) benutzen?

Ich weiß nicht wie und wann. Bitte erläutern Sie mir das.

Comment: Könntest du bitte etwas mehr Kontext zu deiner Frage liefern um zu erkennen, wo das Problem ist?

Comment: Um mit zu   das ist ja das problem

Comment: Du hast das Problem noch nicht verdeutlicht.

Comment: How can i use (um zu)?

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27417/unterschied-zwischen-um-zu-und-zum

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/um-zu-oder-nur-zu

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37283/usage-of-zum-and-um-zu

Answer (score 2):

Suche bitte in deinem Grammatikbuch nach dem **Infinitivsatz**. Im Speziellen nach dem **Finalsatz**.

Solche *Infinitivsätze* ersetzen *Objekte* oder *Objektsätze*.

> Er schaut **zum Verständnis** ins Buch.

Das Stück *zum Verständnis* ist ein Präpositionalobjekt zu *schauen*. Alternativ kann man auch *für das Verständnis/Verstehen* sagen, aber das klingt nicht so gut.

Dieses Präpositionalobjekt kann durch einen Objektsatz ersetzt werden.

> *Er* schaut ins Buch, **damit *er* (es) versteht**.
>
> *Er* schaut ins Buch, **dass *er* (es) versteht**.

Infinitivsätze mit **um** ersetzen Objektsätze mit **damit**. Manchmal wird an dieser Stelle statt *damit* auch *dass* verwendet.

> Er schaut ins Buch, **um (es) zu verstehen.**

Man kann den Infinitivsatz immer dann verwenden, wenn das Subjekt (hier *er*) sich nicht ändert. Deutschsprecher verwenden den Infinitivsatz fast immer, wenn es möglich ist.

---

Der Infinitivsatz kann Objekte und den Objektsatz auch an vielen anderen Stellen ersetzen. Wichtig ist dabei, dass *entweder* das Subjekt im Hauptsatz und im Objektsatz **gleich sind**:

> *Er* sieht ein, **dass *er* viel mehr nachlesen muss**.
>
> *Er* sieht ein, **viel mehr nachlesen zu müssen**.

*Oder*, dass das Subjekt des Objektsatzes ein Objekt des Hauptsatzes ist.

> Sie wollte *ihn* überzeugen, **dass *er* sein Buch liest.**
>
> Sie wollte *ihn* überzeugen, **sein Buch zu lesen.**

Dieser Fall kommt aber nicht so häufig vor.

Die häufigste Einleitung des Objektsatzes überhaupt ist *dass*. Der  Infinitivsatz hat dann meistens keine einleitende Konjunktion. *Damit* kommt am zweithäufigsten vor, und wird im Infinitivsatz durch *um* ersetzt. Außerdem gibt es noch *anstatt dass* und *ohne dass*, bei denen einfach das *dass* ausgelassen wird.

> *Sie* schaut ins Buch, **anstatt dass *sie* zuerst herumfragt.**
>
> *Sie* schaut ins Buch, **anstatt zuerst herumzufragen.**
>
> *Sie* liest, **ohne dass *sie* eine Pause macht.**
>
> *Sie* liest, **ohne eine Pause zu machen.**