# Kann man die Subjuktion „um” bei „um...zu”-Sätzen weglassen?

Tags: phrase, infinitive

Ich habe anderen Diskussionen, die sich auf dieses Thema beziehen, aber Ich habe die Antwort meiner Frage nicht gefunden. Es geht um einem einfachen Zweifel:

Sind die beiden Sätze hierunter austauschbar? Oder haben sie verschiedene Bedeutungen?

"Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, **um** Spanisch **zu** lernen."

vs.

"Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, Spanisch **zu** lernen."

Comment: Ich habe hier https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46895/um-zu-benutzen/46896#46896 zu diesem Thema schon etwas geschrieben. Generell unterscheiden sich Infinitivsätze mit *um zu* dadurch von den "normalen" Infinitivsätzen, dass sie Objektsätze ersetzen, die durch *damit* eingeleitet werden.

Comment: @Janka Ich habe deine Antwort (link) gelesen, aber es ist mir noch nicht so klar... Wann sagt man "Ich fahre nach Italien, um Italienisch zu lernen" und "Ich fahre nach Italien, Italienisch zu lernen"? Ich habe es so verstanden (bin ich richtig?): Mit "um...zu" kann den Satz mit "damit" schreiben "Ich fahre nach Italien, damit ich Italienisch lerne" und mit nur "zu", kann ich ein "dass-Satz ("weil" eigentlich)" schreiben "Ich fahre nach Italien, weil ich Italienisch lernen möchte". Ist das die Unterschied? Ich bin total "verwirrt" (confused).

Comment: Der Unterschied ist, dass es archaisch oder poetisch klingt, wenn man bei einem "um … zu"-Satz das "um" weglässt. Wie die bisherigen Antworten ausführen, gibt es im Allgemeinen einen Unterschied in der Funktion von Nebensätzen mit oder ohne "um", aber in diesem Fall ist es einfach nur eine veraltete Form, die in der Poesie oder in alten Geschichten aber nicht im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch vorkommt.

Comment: @hajef Du beantwortest die gestellte Frage - ob die Sätze einen Unterschied machen -, während die bisherigen Antworten nur - verkürzend, wenn nicht gar falsch - erklären, dass diese Konstruktion nicht existieren würde. Magst du eine Antwort aus deinem Kommentar machen? Würde von mir einen Upvote bekommen.

Answer (score 1):

Infinitivsätze ersetzen Objektsätze. Es gibt drei Sorten mit einleitender Konjunktion. Diese drücken besondere Beziehungen aus:

Grund – **um … zu**:

> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, um Spanisch zu lernen.
>
> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, damit er Spanisch lernt.

Auslassung – **ohne … zu**:

> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, ohne Spanisch zu lernen.
>
> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, ohne dass er Spanisch lernt.

Widerspruch – **anstatt … zu**:

> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, anstatt Spanisch zu lernen.
>
> Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, anstatt dass er Spanisch lernt.

---

Und daneben gibt es noch die "normalen" Infinitivsätze ohne einleitende Konjunktion. Diese Infinitivsätze kann man nicht wie in deinem Beispiel verwenden.

> <s>Er macht Urlaub in Spanien, Spanisch zu lernen.</s>

Stattdessen dienen sie einfach nur dazu, einen Objektsatz mit *dass* zu vermeiden.

> Erst macht er Urlaub in Spanien, und nun jammert er, dass er kein Geld mehr hat.
>
> Erst macht er Urlaub in Spanien, und nun jammert er, kein Geld mehr zu haben.

Comment: Die Beispiele mit *um, ohne, anstatt* sind gerade keine Objektsätze, sondern adverbial.

Comment: Bitte editiere es. Ich bin mit den genauen Begrifflichkeiten nicht so vertraut.

Answer (score 1):

Mit *um* werden adverbiale Infinitivkonstruktionen eingeleitet, die einen **Zweck** bezeichnen. Ein passendes Fragewort ist *wozu*.

> **Wozu** fährst du nach Spanien?
> – Ich fahre nach Spanien, **um mein Spanisch zu verbessern**.
>
> = Ich fahre nach Spanien, **weil ich mein Spanisch verbessern möchte.**

Die "uneingeleitete" Infinitivkonstruktion fungiert dagegen als **Subjekt-** oder **Objektsatz**. Ein passendes Fragewort ist *was*.

> **Was** war dir wichtig?
> – **Spanisch zu lernen**, war mir wichtig.
>
> = **Das Lernen der Sprache** war mir wichtig.

> **Was** hast du vergessen?
> – Ich habe vergessen, **ihr zum Geburtstag zu gratulieren**.
>
> Ich habe **die Gratulation** vergessen.

Einen Objektsatz kann man im Gegensatz zu einem Adverbialsatz in der Regel nicht einfach weglassen.

> Ich fahre nach Spanien.
> *Mir war wichtig.
> *Ich habe vergessen.

Man kann das *um* nicht einfach weglassen oder ergänzen, da Adverbialsätze und Objektsätze unterschiedliche Funktionen im Satz erfüllen. Der folgende Satz ist ungrammatisch, weil *fahren* nicht mit einem Objektsatz stehen kann.

> *Ich fahre nach Spanien, mein Spanisch zu verbessern.

<sub>Uneingeleitete Infinitivkonstruktionen konnten früher finale Bedeutung haben, aber das ist heute nicht mehr der Fall.</sub>

Comment: Ich bin relativ sicher, dass dein letztes Beispiel korrekt ist, wenn auch nicht häufig gebraucht. Anderes Beispiel: »Er zog aus, die Welt zu erobern«. (Oder ist es das, was du mit deinem letzten, klein geschriebenen Satz meinst?)

Comment: @Philipp Ich werte das als veraltet und werde es jedenfalls keinem Lerner zumuten, der gerade erst dabei ist, sich adverbiale Infinitivkonstruktionen und Sätze anzueignen.

Comment: Stimmt natürlich. Umgangssprachlich ist anders, und Deutschneulinge haben andere Prioritäten. Aber auch in moderner Literatur findet man sowas noch, etwa, wenn ein epischer (nicht unbedingt archaisierender) Ton angeschlagen werden soll. Ein Beispiel muss ich dir gerade leider schuldig bleiben.

Answer (score 1):

Tl,dr: Man kann, man sollte aber nicht

---

Inhaltlich sind die beiden Sätze identisch und die Funktion des Nebensatzes ist auch dieselbe. Der Unterschied ist, dass es archaisch oder poetisch klingt, wenn man bei einem "um … zu"-Satz das "um" weglässt. Wie die bisherigen Antworten ausführen, gibt es im Allgemeinen einen Unterschied in der Funktion von Nebensätzen mit oder ohne "um", aber in diesem Fall ist es einfach nur eine veraltete Form, die in der Poesie oder in alten Geschichten noch vorkommt aber nicht mehr im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch.