# Wieso gibt es kein "um" in diesem Satz?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

In diesem Satz:

> Durch unsere Arbeit treffen wir immer wieder Menschen, die sehr nervös sind, Deutsch zu sprechen.

Normalerweise muss "um" in diesem Satz stehen ([...] die sehr nervös sind, *um* Deutsch zu sprechen). z.b:

> Zürich bietet das ideale Umfeld, um Deutsch und zahlreiche weitere Sprachen zu lernen.

Comment: Nein, korrekt lautet der Satz ebenfalls "Ich finde es schwierig, Deutsch zu lernen".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: @infinitezero Ich hab' das Beispiel verändert. ich hoffe, dass es nun Fehlerfrei klingt.

Comment: Der erste Satz macht keinen Sinn, weder mit noch ohne "um". Es sollte wahrscheinlich mit "Wir treffen Menschen..." anfangen. Es wäre auch hilfreich, wenn du zeigen würdest, wo genau im Satz du "um" erwartest.

Comment: @RoToRa Vermerkt.

Comment: Verwandt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54291/kann-man-die-subjuktion-um-bei-um-zu-s%c3%a4tzen-weglassen/54293#54293

Comment: Der Satz wird deutlich leichter verständlich, wenn man *sehr nervös sind* durch *zu nervös sind* ersetzt. Das *um* macht den Satz zwar lesbarer, ist aber m. E. nicht zwingend erforderlich.

Answer (score 7):

Der Satz bekommt mit einem *um* eine andere Bedeutung.

> Durch unsere Arbeit treffen wir Menschen, die sehr nervös sind, um Deutsch zu sprechen.

Das würde bedeuten, Ihr trefft Menschen um Deutsch zu sprechen, und zwar Menschen, die sehr nervös sind, aber nicht notwendig nervös sind, weil es ans Deutschsprechen geht.

Wer in die Schweiz fährt, um Deutsch zu lernen, der ergreift eine Maßnahme, um ein Ziel zu erreichen (um-zu).

Richtig wäre:

> In China treffen wir Schweizer, die dort arbeiten, um Deutsch zu sprechen.

Semantisch merkt man, dass die Schweizer kaum in China arbeiten, um dort Deutsch zu sprechen, sondern dass sich das Um-zu auf das treffen, also unsere Motive beziehen muss.

Es soll aber gesagt werden, dass Menschen getroffen werden, die es nervös macht, Deutsch zu sprechen. Das ist keine beabsichtigte Folge sondern ein unerwünschter Seiteneffekt.

Eine andere, semantisch aber bizarre Interpretation wäre noch, dass die Menschen, die ihr trefft, nervös sind um Deutsch zu sprechen. Das bedürfe einer merkwürdigen psychischen Störung, die bewirkt, dass nur in nervösem Zustand Deutsch gesprochen werden kann.

> Durch unsere Arbeit treffen wir Menschen, die mit Wörterbüchern ausgestattet sind, um Deutsch zu sprechen.

Auch hier würde ein *Um-zu* Sinn ergeben, diesmal läge das Motiv bei der Sprecherposition.

Answer (score 1):

Dort ist kein *um* nötig. Das würde den Satz sogar entstellen. Die Konjunktion *um* stellt einen Wirkung-Ursache Zusammenhang her, d.h. für eine Tatsache wird eine Begründung beigeordnet, die meist eine Absicht (purpose) ausdrückt. Zum Beispiel:

> Ich ließ den Apfel fallen, ...

Aha, das war sicher ein Versehen.

> um die Erdanziehungskraft zu demonstrieren, ließ ich den Apfel fallen

Achso, das war beabsichtigt!

Natürlich ist niemand absichtlich nervös, und ein Nutzen kann daraus auch nicht gezogen werden. Tatsächlich ist es genau anders herum: die Nervosität folgt erst aus dem Versuch, Deutsch zu sprechen.

Dabei wird hier auf Konjunktionen ganz verzichtet. Das ist tatsächlich etwas eigenartig. Wo die Ursachen und Absichten liegen, das mag individuell unterschiedlich sein, daher wird auf eine spezifische Begründung verzichtet. Im endeffekt ließt es dich wie eine Verbalphrase, d.h. *nervös deutsch zu sprechen*. Das muss ulkig wirken, da *sprechen* sonst nicht das Hilfsverb *sein* (bzw. *waren*) regiert.

Beachtlich ist, dass die Prämisse meist keine echte Aktivität, sondern eine Art medio-passiv darstellt ("fallen", "fallen lassen", "sich fallen lassen" ist eben ein klassisches Beispiel dafür), die eine Begründung genau dann erfordert, wenn Aktivität suggeriert werden soll. In Negation ist wiederum der Beisatz eher inaktiv, "Ich kaufe Nahrung, *um nicht* zu verhungern".

---

Darüber hinaus gibt es weitere Formulierungen mit *um*. Da ist eine gewisse Formulierung mit *zu*, insbesondere *zu ... um zu...*: "Sie waren *zu* nervös, *um zu* sprechen" (they were *too* nervous, *about* being *to* speak German). Da spielt negation wieder eine Rolle. Das wird aber nie mit *sehr* ausgedrückt, welches im Gegenteil intensivierend wirkt. Vermutlich hattest du das verwechselt.

---

Gänzlich falsch ist dein Vorschlag nicht, es scheitert nur auf der semantischen Ebene. Zwar wird Nervosität in der Regel als unbeabsichtigter Störfaktor zu verstehen sein. Epistemologisch, als Ausdruck der Vorfreude sozusagen, ist aber erkennbar, was gemeint war (bspw. "they were keen to" oder "affraid to")